# Add link button from server side in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i am trying to add asp:LinkButton in specific div. but its not working. It just add text but link not showing. I don't know where i am wrong. Below is what i am trying to do.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div id="divTitle" runat="server">
    //I am trying to add link button here
    </div>
</div>
```

//Server side code is below

```
Int32 counter = 1;
divTitle.Controls.Clear();
foreach (DataRow dritem in dt.Rows)
{
divTitle.InnerHtml = "<asp:LinkButton ID='lbl" + counter++ + "'  runat='server'  CommandArgument='" + dritem["DocumentName"] + "' OnClick='ViewDocument'  Visible='true'>" + dritem["UpDocumentName"] + "</asp:LinkButton>";
}
```

Comment: You must to use RenderControl

Comment: Using the InnerHtml you just adding a plain HTML to a specific location. You have add the control to that location. You can check the following url: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx

Comment: This is what a repeater is for, you should avoid manually adding controls in Web Forms.

Comment: You can use Visible property for show or hide LinkButton.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this ...

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div id="divTitle" runat="server">
    //I am trying to add link button here
    </div>
</div>
```

and in the server side ...

```
Control divTitleControl = this.Page.FindControl("divTitle");
LinkButton linkButton = new LinkButton();
divTitleControl.Controls.Add(linkButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

The string you are assigning to divTitle.InnerHtml is just a string. Try this:
(or bind your data to repeater as suggested in comments - which would be the correct way I guess)

```
//....
var button = new LinkButton();
button.CommandArgument = dritem["DocumentName"];
button.Click += ViewDocument;
button.Text = dritem["UpDocumentName"];

divTitle.Controls.Add(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to create an ASP control by adding it as inner html, but that ignores how a .NET server deals with asp pages and how your browser interprets the given page.

When you add InnerHTML to a div, in your server side code, that is taken by the .NET server as html code that it does not need to parse.  But ASP controls have to be parsed into actual HTML tags so that your browser can recognize them.

Since it is not parsed, your browser gets a tag that says `<asp:Link...` and there is no such tag in valid html.

So what you have to do is either add valid html as innerHTML, something like

```
divTitle.InnerHtml = "<a ID='lbl" + counter++ + ...
```

or add the ASP control as a created control.  Since you are wanting to connect that control to a click event handler, you really need to do this second option

```
var MyLinkButton = new LinkButton();
MyLinkButton.ID = "lbl" + counter++;
MyLinkButton.Text = dritem["UpDocumentName"];
MyLinkButton.CommandArgument = dritem["DocumentName"];
MyLinkButton.Click += ViewDocument;
divTitle.Controls.Add(MyLinkButton);
```

Comment: what is the signature of your click event handler?  does it look like this: `void ViewDocument(object sender, EventArgs e)` ?  If you used a method that does not accept the right parameters, the runtime will not be able to find the right signature, and so will not make the call.

Comment: protected void ViewDocument(object sender, EventArgs e)